flutter icons after the latest version
i have a problem related to flutter icons, after upgrading flutter, and running the old project on the emulator or the mobile also after i run 'flutter build apk' in the terminal and use the release app on the mobile ,icons can not be shown like this 
this is pubspec.yaml : uses-material-design: true, the project works well on web page but on the emulator or a mobile i have this problem!!

Try to run the following commands in the terminal:
flutter clean

flutter pub get

if it doesn't work
flutter pub cache repair

